# JS TypeError showing on click for unrelated code

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am stumped as to why I am getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.target.className.includes is not a function
  <anonymous> https://domain/jco/v2022-main.1.2.js:978
  EventListener.handleEvent* https://domain/jco/v2022-main.1.2.js:855

  <anonymous> https://domain/jco/v2022-main.1.2.js:978
  (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
  <anonymous> https://domain/jco/v2022-main.1.2.js:855
```

The lines in question are part of a large event delegation section, that we use because we are using JS to replace just the content on page changes rather than reloading the entire page.  The code below is the event delegation minus all of the href code (which is rather long).  The numbers in the error message correspond to:

855 - `$('mstrwrap').addEventListener('click', function(e) {`

978 - `else if (e.target.className.includes('closeit')) {`

```
$('mstrwrap').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // set eventlisteners for all A HREF links
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'A') {
    // actions for clicks on href links        
  }
  // end if 'A' link
    
  // clicks of divs, svg, other non-href
  // check if is myList link
  else if (e.target.id.includes('add2lst')) {
    // add tourid to MyList
    addToMyList();
  }
  else if (e.target.id.includes('svd2lst')) {
    // remove tourid from MyList
    removeFromMyList();
  }

  else if (e.target.id.includes('mlPhnDiv')) {
    // toggle myList on phones
    $('mlPhnDiv').classList.toggle('mlrvl');
  }

  // check if is close nav button
  else if (e.target.className.includes('closeit')) {
    var thisNav = e.target.parentNode.id;
    var thisNvBtn = 'nvbtn' + thisNav.match(/\d+/g);
    // manually close nav panels
    $(thisNav).style.maxHeight = '0';
    $(thisNvBtn).classList.remove('nvopen');
  }

  // show hide nav more trips functions
  else if (e.target.id.includes('showtrips')) {
    showTrips();
  } 
  else if (e.target.id.includes('hidetrips')) {
    hideTrips();
  }

  // phone nav menu open close
  // show hide phone nav
  else if (e.target.id.includes('phNav')) {
    tglPhnNav();
  }

  // any other click ignore
  else {
    return;
  }
  // end set eventListeners
});
```

The thing that is stumping me is that the error message is generated when I click on the #phNav button which should target `else if (e.target.id.includes('phNav')) {` which is further down the code and not the .closeit code.

Everything works as expected, including the .closeit section as well as the hidetrips / showtrips functions in between closeit and phNav.  The click target for phNav is an svg.

Are there any quirks of JS that might explain this or can anyone see something I missed?

Some additional bits, we are not using jQuery just a snippet that saves characters by setting $ = document.getElementById.  And the tglPhnNav code is below:

```
// phone nav buttons
function tglPhnNav() {
  if ($('phmenu').style.display === 'flex') {
    $('phmenu').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    $('phmenu').style.display = 'flex';
  }
}
```

As requested by NiceBooks in the comments, the svg link that when clicked is having the error

```
<div id="btmnvbar" class="horz">
  <svg width="35" height="35">removed for brevity</svg>
  <svg width="35" height="35">removed for brevity</svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 80" width="32" height="32" fill="#ffe" id="phNav"><rect width="100" height="12" rx="8"></rect><rect y="30" width="100" height="12" rx="8"></rect><rect y="60" width="100" height="12" rx="8"></rect></svg>
</div>
```

Update: The earlier issue of not firing the phNav code has been resolved, but the primary issue of the unrelated error message remains.

Comment: Which browser are you using ?

Comment: You can try `e.target.classList.contains('closeit')`

Comment: @NiceBooks - I am using latest Firefox (Win 11) for developing, but have also checked with Chrome & Edge (Win11) and Chrome (Android).

Comment: No idea why this error is caused, but do you really have an element named `mstrwrap` ? Or is it a class/attribute ?

Comment: @NiceBooks - changing to contains actually makes it worse, as it stops the closeit function.  And yes mstrwrap is the overall container for the webpages.

Comment: Is there a console error when using `classList.includes` ?

Comment: @NiceBooks  When using "contains", I get "not a function" errors when clicking the closeit or phNav links and both functions disabled.  Using "includes", clicking closeit function works as expected, but clicking phNav generates the error as described in my post.

Comment: Are you using SVG ? Please post code as HTML/Js snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the proper selector. Try console logging the selected element to check if it is available in the document.

```js
console.log('tag', $('mstrwrap'));
console.log('id', $('#mstrwrap'));
console.log('class', $('.mstrwrap'));
```

Also you should use `e.target.classList.contains('closeit')` instead of `e.target.className.includes('closeit')`.

EDIT: As the #phNav is child of another element that has multiple child elements try doing this. I might solve the problem.

```js
  // phone nav menu open close
  // show hide phone nav
  else if (e.target.parentNode.id == 'btmnvbar') {
    tglPhnNav();
  }
```

instead of

```js
  // phone nav menu open close
  // show hide phone nav
  else if (e.target.id.includes('phNav')) {
    tglPhnNav();
  }
```

Comment: I am sure the mstrwrap call is correct as all of the items in the event delegation code are triggering as expected.  Even the `closeit` function triggers as expected.  It is the `phNav` call that is somehow triggering an error message blamed on `closeit`.

`<div id="mstrwrap">...</div>`

Comment: Understanding the problem with only javascript is a little hard, try providing a codepen for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks but targeting the parent div would cause clicks on the other two icons to also trigger the menu, which we don't want.  But the main quandary of this post is why is clicking `#phNav` causing an error message related to the `.closeit` code?

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, this error seems impossible.
Why wouldn't the `className` property, being a `String` have the `includes` method ?

After googling & some practice, it appears the problem is quite simple.
SVG elements have a deprecated `className` property ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement#svgelement.classname)), which is an instance of the `SVGAnimatedString` class, which is hardly related to `String`. `SVGElement`s do have the `parentNode` property which is inherited from the `Element` interface.

> An SVGAnimatedString that reflects the value of the class attribute on the given element, or the empty string if class is not present. This attribute is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of this specification. Authors are advised to use Element.classList instead.

Solution: use `.classList.contains('closeit')` or `.is('.closeit')` instead.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but the target for the `.closeit` function is a simple div containing the letter X `<div class="closeit" title="close nav menu">x</div>`.  The svg is the `#phNav` target, no className involved just an ID.  But clicking on the phNav target generates the error message about the `className.includes('closeit')`.  Both are under the <nav> section, but on different trees at different levels so shouldn't bubble up to each other.

Comment: You have applied your click listener on the mstrwrap container. You click anywhere (eg: a rect) inside the #phNav svg. The listener is executed -> The `evt.target` is the rect -> The `evt.currentTarget` is the mstrrap.  The id of the rect is compared against add2lst, svd2lst,mlPhnDiv & results in false each time -> The rect (an svg element)'s *className* is accessed -> Error due to inexistant includes method.